# How can I rotate individual instances based on their center points?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to rotate instances of a text that I split using the "Split to Instances" node.
However, the pivot point for each instance is currently on the same point.
How can I set the pivot point of each instance to its own center, individually?

[image]

[image]